# Change to a new version of the JDK?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I want to change the JDK version 1.5.15 to 1.6.29. If I do this, will any problems occur in an existing application that was developed under JDK 1.5.15?

Comment: Oh, and provide some useful details while you are at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically that shouldn't be a problem. But I would have a bad feeling doing this without enough test coverage. There was a project in my company were they were also changing to a newer java version (don't remember which one). Everything seems to be fine but after some time a few bugs were rising. It turned out that one developer illegally relied on the order of a Collection class. The bug was caused by a changed implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Java SE 6 Compatibility with J2SE 5.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137541.html) document. It should be ok, but please go through the [incompatibilities](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137541.html#incompatibilities) section just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile your code with new JDK(1.6.9) classpath than you are fine no need to change anything.
If code change require follow some online JDK 1.5 to 1.6 migration tutorials already available.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to test this. It probably is possible to compile and run your application with JDK1.6, but some behavior might have changed in a subtle way. An example of such a change between JDK1.6 and JDK1.7 I recently encountered is posted [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700073/drag-and-drop-differences-between-jdk1-6-and-jdk1-7). Although the project compiled just fine, testing (unit tests, integration tests and manual testing) revealed some issues which weren't caught by the compiler

Answer (score 0):

No i don't think it will create any Problem.