# How to drag file or folder from windows explorer to java?

Tags: java, user-interface, drag-and-drop, jpanel, jcomponent

How to drag file or folder from windows explorer to Jpanel or text faild ...
and how to calling desktop and use it?

```
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class test extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4487732343062917781L;
JFileChooser fc;
JButton clear;
JTextArea dropZone, console;
JSplitPane childSplitPane, parentSplitPane;
PrintStream ps;

  public test() {
super(new BorderLayout());

fc = new JFileChooser();;
fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
fc.setDragEnabled(true);
fc.setControlButtonsAreShown(false);
fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);               


JPanel fcPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
fcPanel.add(fc, BorderLayout.CENTER);

clear = new JButton("Clear All");
clear.addActionListener(this);
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
buttonPanel.add(clear, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

JPanel leftUpperPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
leftUpperPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
leftUpperPanel.add(fcPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
leftUpperPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);


JScrollPane leftLowerPanel = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
leftLowerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
dropZone = new JTextArea();
dropZone.setColumns(20);
dropZone.setLineWrap(true);
dropZone.setRows(5);
dropZone.setDragEnabled(true);
dropZone.setDropMode(javax.swing.DropMode.INSERT);
dropZone.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Selected files/folders"));
leftLowerPanel.setViewportView(dropZone);


childSplitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,
        leftUpperPanel, leftLowerPanel);
childSplitPane.setDividerLocation(400);
childSplitPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(480, 650));

console = new JTextArea();
console.setColumns(40);
console.setLineWrap(true);
console.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Console"));

parentSplitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
                childSplitPane, console);
parentSplitPane.setDividerLocation(480);
parentSplitPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 650));

add(parentSplitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

}

```
public void setDefaultButton() {
getRootPane().setDefaultButton(clear);
```

}

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
if (e.getSource() == clear) {
    dropZone.setText("");

}
}

/**
 * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event-dispatching thread.
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
//Make sure we have nice window decorations.
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
try {
  //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaBlackStarLookAndFeel");
    for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            break;
        }
    }
}catch (Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}

//Create and set up the window.
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Consolidator!");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

//Create and set up the menu bar and content pane.
test demo = new test();
demo.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
frame.setContentPane(demo);

//Display the window.
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
demo.setDefaultButton();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
//Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
//creating and showing this application's GUI.
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}}
```

i need to make this code accept file and folder from windows not just from file chooser

Comment: I don't understand this question... what is it you want to do once a file/folder has been dragged onto your program?

Comment: Do you mean? how can I make it so that I can drag a file from windows explorer to my java program, and then open it?

Comment: i want to drag file and folder from win explorer to jpanel

Comment: Start with [Introduction to DnD](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer - nice link. Very interesting reading.

Comment: See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8700073/1076463) which contains an SSCCE of dropping a file onto a panel

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try this page, [here](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/filedrop/), then open a FileInputStream and output the file onto the JPanel.